Como instalar un certificado en xampp y verlo en un dominio que lo redireccione a un dns tipo A
una duda tengo ya un dominio el cual le puse en las dns la IP dónde se almacena mi proyecto, funciona correctamente pero es http. Compré del mismo proveedor del dominio un certificado y configure xampp desde instalarle el certificado y ponerle la llave pero por alguna razón cuando accedo a la URL con https dice que tarda en cargar y yo creo que es poque no puede entrar al https y con http si es posible. si alguien podría ayudarme lo agradecería mucho gracia
